# How to download executable(ANTLRv4) to generate files during pip install

Tags: python, pip, antlr, antlr4, setuptools

The library I'm working on generates python files according to an executable (which turns [ANTLRv4](https://github.com/antlr/antlr4) .g4 files into python files), and I have the following install step:

```
import os
import subprocess
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install


class AntlrInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        output_dir = compile_grammar()
        print(f"Compiled ANTLRv4 grammar in {output_dir}")
        install.run(self)


def compile_grammar():
    parser_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "my_project/grammar")
    subprocess.check_output(
        ["antlr", "MyGrammar.g4", "-Dlanguage=Python3", "-visitor", "-o", "gen"],
        cwd=parser_dir,
    )
    # The result is created in the subfolder `gen`
    return os.path.join(parser_dir, "gen")


setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        "setuptools",
        "antlr4-python3-runtime==4.9.2",
        ...
    ],
    cmdclass={"install": AntlrInstallCommand},
    license="MIT",
    python_requires=">=3.6",
)
```

Which works great if I'm `pip install`'ing the project on a machine that has `antlr` installed (since I'm calling it via `subprocess`).

Ideally, attempting to do this on a machine that doesn't have `antlr` installed would first install the executable(with the correct version) in either a system directory like `/usr/bin`, or whatever relevant python bin directory we're working in, **but right now it errors out with the following message(which is expected)**:

```
  running install
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'antlr'
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for my_project
```

I see a couple of solutions each with slight caveats:

- `sympy` uses ANTLR, but it requires the user to install `antlr` first. [See here](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/tree/645bbb06cd289165a9144d4c2c64bf17b664f8ac#regenerate-experimental-latex-parserlexer)
- [`setuptools-antlr`](https://github.com/ferraith/setuptools-antlr) allows me to download an antlr jar as a giant blob in a python package, and then I can invoke it here. However, the version doesn't match mine (which is 4.9.2).
- [`java2python`](https://github.com/natural/java2python) precompiles the files for me and writes them into the github repo. However, [these files](https://github.com/natural/java2python/blob/master/java2python/lang/JavaParser.py) are extremely large and are very hard to read as they're autogenerated. If I slightly modify the grammar and don't modify the parser it would also lead to unexpected bugs. As a result, I would like to hide this complexity from the repository as it's tangential to development.

If I can get the right version of the antlr binary and be able to invoke it at install time, that would be optimal. Otherwise I'm okay with picking one of these alternatives. Any suggestions for either case would be appreciated.

Comment: can't you use  containerization tool, like docker etc for your use case? just for hint, we did one project that was using nodejs reacts etc and we didn't had java runtime, and we didn't want to install either. we simply used docker to run java and antlr4.

Comment: This is a python library that will be published on pypi so it's unreasonable to assume that the user needs to have docker as a prerequisite and that the user must be executing the library code from inside a container that I provide. I think that is a strictly worse option than any of the existing solutions to the problem

Comment: I have to do this with one of my build tools. I embed a minimal copy of the Java RTE (jrecreate) and the Antlr4 jar in the package. Then, I just call process() on java -jar antlr4 jar. You should not rely on users setting up a single thing. Just package it up yourself, getting the version of Java and Antlr4 tool you want.

Comment: @kaby76 Seems reasonable if I can somehow embed it into the package. Do you have an example I can go off of? (and feel free to write it as an answer for points if you want)

Comment: The tool I wrote is for C#, so I can't help on how to embed files in a Python package. Alternatevly, the best source (reliable/official) for downloading the antlr4 complete .jar file is Maven Central, something like https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/antlr/antlr4/<your version>/antlr4-<your version>-complete.jar . As far as running jrecreate, I can't remember how I did that. But, the one I created was 32MB, which is a bit. But, you can cache the downloaded files on your file system so you don't have to repeat.